# Android Studio Login to Registration Form

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, registration, mobile-application

I'm fairly new with Android Studio and I'm current working with a Login Form for my mobile application. However, I want to make the login page "register" by adding first time users into the database and having that user always access the application without relogging rather than constantly checking if the user's account is stored and requires a login every time.

Can someone share me helpful documents or codes on this matter. Thanks!

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences , Realm , Sqlite ... to store user preferences in device. If you go to google and search for "how to store user preferences  in android" you can find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this via **Shared Preference**.You can save the user info and retrieve it next time when the app is opened and check whether the user is already registered or not and his details etc.

[Here is a example of Shared Preference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your users to remain logged into the application everytime then one way is to use Shared Preferences in android. Shared Preferences will save the users credentials in a local storage and the user need not to enter them everytime.